# Match and concatenate formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel columns. I need to compare the two columns (A & B) for matches and append everything after the delimiter, like so:

```
Column A
123456;cc01
654321;cc02
333333;cc03
444444;cc04
555555;cc05

Column B
111111
222222
333333
444444
555555
```

The output should be the following due to three matches in this example:

```
Column C
333333;cc03
444444;cc04
555555;cc05
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are the digits appearing before the semicolon in column A always the same width?

Comment: see if this works for you, put this in C1 and copy down: `=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B3&"*",A:A,0)),"")`

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this array formula (line break added for readability):

```
= IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$6-LEFT($A$2:$A$6,FIND(";",$A$2:$A$6)-1))=0,
  ROW($A$2:$A$6)),ROW($A2)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$6))+1)),"")
```

Note this is an array formula, so you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the formula.

See working example below. I have this formula in cell `C2` and dragged down.

[image]

This formula also works if you insert rows with new data. See below.

[image]

Comment: BTW, You can replace the long `ROW($A2)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$6))+1` with `ROW(1:1)` and achieve the same thing.

Comment: @ScottCraner Correct. However, I almost always avoid doing or suggesting this just because depending on where the data is located, if you insert a row (depending on where the row is inserted), this can screw up the formula.

Comment: Your `Row($A2)` is the same as `Row(2:2)` so i do not see how this will not react the exact same.  Also `MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$6))` can be written as `ROW($A$2)`  As I see it yours has all the same problems if a row is inserted into the region of formulas. https://imgur.com/a/a2c4n Column C is my formula and Column d yours.  As you can see I added a row at row 2 both formulas acted the same.  Now if I add a row to the data your formula errors and mine does not: https://imgur.com/a/t0LNv

Comment: And in the case you just posted mine does the exact same, without issue.  Now the real issue is how to append the list at the bottom and not need to resize the formula I will edit mine to do that.

Comment: @ScottCraner I just tried to insert a new row into my formula *and add new data* and it works (see my post, I edited). My guess for the reason you are seeing the error is because the formula is looking for a `;` in each row of the `A` column, which is causing the error. Anyway, I agree that `MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$6))` is the same as `ROW($A$2)` and I am not arguing this. My point is that if for example this data started on the 5th row (e.g. `A5:B9`) and a row is inserted for example at row 3, then `ROW(1:1)` in the formula will change to `ROW(2:2)` for the formula in `C5` (now `C6`) which is bad.

Comment: um except If you only add a row to the data and not the formula yours will not iterate correctly: https://imgur.com/a/73dga as you can see I added it to my Row 2 and the reference of `Row($A2)` changed to `Row($A3)` thus skipping the 2nd outcome.  I needed to reset the formula from the first to make them all appear.

Comment: @ScottCraner In other words, if cell `C5` is `=ROW($A5)-MIN(ROW($A$5:$A$9))+1`, this *always* evaluates to `1` even if a row is inserted *anywhere* in the spreadsheet. As opposed to if `C5` is `=ROW(1:1)`, this only evaluates to `1` if a row is inserted *below row 5*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163425/discussion-between-scott-craner-and-imaginaryhuman072889).

Answer (score 1):

Or this regular entered formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$6)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH(--LEFT($A$1:$A$6,FIND(";",$A$1:$A$6 & ";")-1),B:B,0))),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Put in the first cell and copy down.

[image]

---

to deal with ever enlargin data use this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))/(ISNUMBER(MATCH(--LEFT($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),
FIND(";",$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)) & ";")-1),B:B,0))),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Still looks like an array formula. Is `AGGREGATE` one of those "automatic" array formulas even if you don't explicitly enter it as one?

Comment: Yes it is, just like SUMPRODUCT,  It has all the limitations of an Array formula, it this case `SMALL(IF())` without the need for Ctrl-Shift-Enter.